# I got this issue The following modules are outdated:

Tags: magento2, third-party-module

Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Dotdigitalgroup_Email data: current version - 2.5.0, required version - 2.6.1

I am using Magento "version": "2.2.7". When i move old hosting to new hosting i got this issue. My PHP version is PHP 7.1 .

How can i fix this issue? I am Beginner with Magento 2. Please some one help me. https://devmag.visibleone.net/favelady/

Comment: module.xml version and version in database(setup_module) table is different.

Comment: if you have access to database then change the version of database same as module.xml

Comment: How can i do for it? any reference links pls?

Comment: you have database access ?

Comment: yes. i have. but i  can't find (setup_module) table.

Comment: have you searched in phpmyadmin?

Comment: yes. now i can see  "beaw_setup_module" (table)

Comment: ok great, now check the version of the same extension in module.xml and "beaw_setup_module" table

Comment: where module.xml ? thanks.

Comment: path : vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/etc/module.xml

Comment: i already tried for it. after then my site can't browse.

Comment: as per the question that error resolved......

Comment: for more issues , you need to check var/logs files....

Comment: yes. i will try. Thanks.

Comment: i still find this error in system.log file.

[2020-01-20 07:06:23] main.ERROR: Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Dotdigitalgroup_Email data: current version - 2.5.0, required version - 2.6.1 [] []

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database fire below query

`SELECT * FROM setup_module WHERE module = 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email'`

and update schema and data version

**OR**

go to your magento root

remove `composer.lock` file

and run `composer install` command it will restart your composer installation and install avaliable latest package for your magento version

Comment: [v1net@server favelady]$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from repo.magento.com: You haven't provided your Magento authentication keys. For instructions, visit https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username:

Comment: when i install composer , i got this instructions message. what should be continue?

Answer (score 0):

You should find **module = 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email'** in the table **setup_module**
then fix Magento version **2.6.1**

Comment: I already updated. But sitll got an error and my site is not working.

Comment: @Nang, please ensure that 'schema_version' and 'data_version' are similar. Then clear cache.